# How to enable error highlighting in HTML with "create method" feature in WebStorm?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, webstorm

I used to have this feature running but not after a recent update!

On line #33, I am getting the expected red color and suggestion to create the variable.

On line #34, I want to have the same feature enabled for the method, which in this case - `continue2()` - is not present in the Angular component, but I am no longer seeing a red text color, no suggestion, and not even a runtime error!

[image]

Comment: what happens if you rename `continue2()` to a different name or Ctrl+click it?

Comment: absolutely nothing! something gone wrong in my IDE settings; before, it would either take me to the method being referenced, or I would get an error "method doesn't exist/unresolved", and a hint to "create method"; now? nothing. Also, if it's referencing an existing method, it would be colored yellow (now you see white), and I would be taken to it with a ctrl+click

Answer (score 1):

If you run into the same issue, look into your `.idea/` folder, then inside an `inspectionProfiles/` folder. There, I found this file below. Line 7 says it all. How that got into my folder structure I am not sure, seems I clicked the wrong option while trying to get rid of popups quickly maybe.

When comparing to other projects, this file doesn't exist! So I deleted it, or you could cherrypick what to delete/leave in it.

[image]

From a Settings perspective, I had the "Unresolved TypeScript function" option `unselected` as shown in the image below; so another way to fix the issue of the post is to select it back.

For this part of the answer: Thanks to Lena P from JetBrains Support.

[image]